# How to increase a float number in a certain amount but still always keeps it under 1?

Tags: python

```
floats = [0.3, 0.45, 0.98, 0.01]
```

I have a list of floats in the range of 0<n<1. For certain numbers, for example, 0.98, I want to increase it so that it is even larger compared to other numbers. For example, I can increase it by multiplying with a co-efficient >1. For example:

```
a = 1.4*0.98
```

But this makes 'a' exceed 1. I want to keep 'a' still in the range of 0<a<1, for example, 0.995. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Compute the amount it would take to *get* to 1, and add a fraction of that.

Comment: `0.98 + 0.01` until it crosses over `1.0`?

Comment: Simply take the midpoint of `a` and 1: `(a + 1) / 2`.

Comment: Based on your question, I'm wondering why you don't just assign it to .9999 directly.

Comment: Can you explain more clearly about what you are trying to do? Question seems to be unclear.

Comment: Seems your data are already normalized, then only you take the decision on which data needs to be increased (or decreased) ? Then you only need to close the gap with the chosen number to 1. 1-0.98 and take a percentage of that fraction. 1-x*% = 1-.098*0.99 + 0.98 would give 99% of the gap between 0.98 and 1, that would be 0.9998

Comment: @L4ur3nt Yes. Can you please write a complete answer?

Comment: I understand what @ScottHunter said. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For arguments sake lets's say that we want to repeatedly uplift each value by some factor. Let that factor be 10% of the difference between the value and 1. Let's do this repeatedly:

```
floats = [0.3, 0.45, 0.98, 0.01]

for _ in range(100):
    floats = [(1 - v) * 0.1 + v for v in floats]

print(floats)
```

**Output:**

```
[0.9999814070207786, 0.9999853912306118, 0.9999994687720222, 0.9999737042151013]
```

Thus all values tend towards 1 but never* get there.

*At some point I guess you could come to a point where this algorithm makes no change to the original value. The uplift factor would therefore need to be adjusted (maybe 1% or even less) depending on how often this is going to happen

Comment: That probably be good because I only want to uplift some values, i.e. 0.98, so it becomes 0.9999 but others remain the same.

Comment: But if I want to uplift 0.45 as well, it becomes 0.9999 too. Ideally it should be something like 0.7. Is that possible?

Comment: @marlon the example was extreme because of the loop over `range(100)`.  If you apply it only once it's a lot more reasonable.  You can change the `0.1` constant to tune the results to your liking.

Comment: @marlon Try changing from 10% to 1% - i.e., 0.1 -> 0.01. There is no definitive answer in terms of what the uplift factor should be. I'm just trying to show an algorithm that will ensure (within reason) that no values reaches 1